# Could dark energy and gravity be explained as same phenomenon?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, spacetime, dark-energy

I have watched [VSouce video on gravity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc4xYacTu-E&t=1s). The idea is that gravity pulling it is just lots of mass bending space-time, and natural direction of movement becomes moving towards the mass, and since we have earth already there we get to sit on top.

This got me thinking what about lack of matter to bend space-time, could it be that space-time bends in the 'opposite' 'direction' like create a slope where everything's natural movement direction is away. Could this be used to explain dark energy's anti-gravity properties?

**EDIT:** Duplicate is about dark matter while this one is about dark energy that are two completely different things...

Comment: @safesphere Hi safesphere, have you watched the video, it would be that path you have to take becomes longer for anything traveling trough the area where there is no mass and would produce the effect that distance is increasing e.g everything is moving away from everything else.

Comment: see cosmological constant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant

Comment: Would downvoter care to elaborate, which part of the video he has found confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gravitational effect of dark energy is repulsive, that of matter is attractive. So these phenomena are different.

> This got me thinking what about lack of matter to bend space-time, could it be that space-time bends in the 'opposite' 'direction'

No it does't. "Lack of matter" is know as "empty universe". This universe has zero curvature of spacetime, because the stress-energy tensor is identically zero. It's spatial curvature is parabolic though.

The empty universe expands linearly which means that neighboring geodesics deviate linearly and not accelerated from each other as in a universe with curved spacetime.

So in conclusion, "lack of matter" doesn't cause repulsive gravity like dark energy.

Comment: You are forgetting cosmological constant. It is not matter, but it contributes to the stress tensor. It leads to de Sitter, anti-de Sitter, or Minkowski universe in the absence of matter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant

Comment: Sure, but the OP meant the 'empty universe' (without the CC), because he thought that this could "explain dark energy's anti-gravity properties". He did not intend to explain dark energy  assuming "lack of matter" plus CC which acts the same way like the CC.  In other words he didn't intend to explain the dark energy by means of the CC.

Comment: It is clearly written 'lack of matter'. CC is not matter, and OP does not specify CC=0 (in fact he does not mention CC at all). So, it is not necessarily zero. Em

Comment: What is the sense in explaining dark energy by means of CC?

Comment: it is the simplest phenomenological model of DE. As for its fundamental origin, we all want to know that! This is one of the reasons to go beyond the standard model of elementary particles.

Comment: @timm Indeed I am trying to replace or rather show the cosmological constant in a different perspective, that it could be same phenomenon as gravity but in a different kind of curvature, that happens due to lack of mass. CC historically was a fudge to begin with...

Comment: @Matas Vaitkevicius: Yes, that's the way I understood and answered your question. The main issue is that if you remove all matter in a universe without CC then there is no gravity anymore and the spacetime is flat. Whereas if you remove all matter while maintaining CC, then there is repulsive gravity only and the universe expands exponentially (and not linearly as in the flat spacetime case).